# How can I create an access token to call the ebay analytics api?

Tags: authentication, ebay-api

I can't generate an access token because apparently the scopes I have provided aren't authorized.

I have created api credentials for the sandbox environment and have followed the steps in the documentation to encode them in the request for an access token (https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-client-credentials-grant.html), and I have experimented with first providing all of my application's scopes in the request and then being more selective (https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/static/oauth-scopes.html#specifying-scopes), but nothing seems to work.

I then found this post (https://forums.developer.ebay.com/questions/23495/application-token-exceeds-the-scope-granted-to-the.html) which suggested using the api explorer (https://developer.ebay.com/my/api_test_tool?index=0&env=sandbox&api=fulfillment&call=order-orderid__GET&variation=json) to generate an access token, but my request was denied with that token as well.

Does anyone know which scopes I have to provide in order to get this access token?

Answer (score 0):

Scope depends on the APIs you want to use once you have the access_token.
I Usually list all scopes so to be able to use any APIs